# Mongo and Pivot

Tags: mongodb, pivot

I need help with mongo in this problem: I have collection stats (UserId, EventId, Count, Date)
in collection are data

### UserID  |  EventId |  Count |  Date

```
1     |     1    |    10  |   01.01.2012
1     |     1    |   15   | 01.02.2012
1     |     2    |   12   | 01.01.2012
2     |     1    |    5   |   01.01.2012
3     |     2    |    10  |   01.01.2012
```

I need this result

### UserId  |  Count_Event_1  | Count_EventId_2

```
  1     |     25          |      12         
  2     |     5           |      0
  3     |     0           |      10
```

Its possibile in Mongo without Map Reduce?
Thank You for your helps.

Answer (score 4):

It is easier, and much faster, to do the job with an `aggregate()`!

We will use a `$project` to create a counter field for each event, filling in the count from the document, if the event matches, zero otherwise. Then we will `$group` by user-id, summing up all the event counters.

For the sake of explanation, let me first show how this looks like hard-coded for the two different events (1 and 2) in your example:

```
db.xx.aggregate([
    { $project: { userid:1,
                  cnt_e1: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$event", 1 ] }, "$count", 0 ] },
                  cnt_e2: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$event", 2 ] }, "$count", 0 ] },
    } },
    { $group: { _id: "$userid", cnt_e1: { $sum: "$cnt_e1" }, cnt_e2: { $sum: "$cnt_e2" } } },  
    { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
])
```

For the given collection:

```
> db.xx.find({},{_id:0})
{ "userid" : 1, "event" : 1, "count" : 10 }
{ "userid" : 1, "event" : 1, "count" : 15 }
{ "userid" : 1, "event" : 2, "count" : 12 }
{ "userid" : 2, "event" : 1, "count" : 5 }
{ "userid" : 3, "event" : 2, "count" : 10 }
```

the result is:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "cnt_e1" : 25,
            "cnt_e2" : 12
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "cnt_e1" : 5,
            "cnt_e2" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "cnt_e1" : 0,
            "cnt_e2" : 10
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

To get this done for variable events, we'll have to generate the projection and the grouping. We'll get an array of all possible events using the `distinct()` command (you might want to define an index on "event"). Then we create the two statements as JSON objects by looping over the array:

```
project = {};
project.$project = {};
project.$project.userid = 1;

group = {};
group.$group = {};
group.$group._id = '$userid'

events = db.xx.distinct( "event" );
events.forEach( function( e ) {
    field = "cnt_e" + e;

    eval("project.$project." + field + " = {}");
    eval("project.$project." + field + ".$cond = []");
    eval("project.$project." + field + ".$cond[0] = {}");
    eval("project.$project." + field + ".$cond[0].$eq = []");
    eval("project.$project." + field + ".$cond[0].$eq[0] = '$event'");
    eval("project.$project." + field + ".$cond[0].$eq[1] = " + e );
    eval("project.$project." + field + ".$cond[1] = '$count'");
    eval("project.$project." + field + ".$cond[2] = 0");

    eval("group.$group." + field + " = {}");
    eval("group.$group." + field + ".$sum = '$" + field + "'");
});

//printjson(project);
//printjson(group);

db.xx.aggregate([
    project,
    group,
    { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
])
```

And the result is the same as above.

Note: the above works for numerical events. If they were strings, you'd have to adapt the generator.

At first sight, this might look more complicated than @Philipp 's mapReduce. But that will not return all events for each user - only the ones that do have a count. For a complete vertical to horizontal mapping you would have to generate the map and the reduce functions as well.

For more information on aggregate(), see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/

Comment: hello ronasta! would you mind having a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36070386/how-can-i-pivot-on-mongodb ???

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this with a [MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/map-reduce/) operation.

Your map function would look like this: (untested!):

```
var mapFunction = function() {
                   var ret = {};
                   ret["Count_Event_" + this.EventId] = this.Count;
                   emit(this.UserId, ret);
               };
```

This emits a series of pairs consisting of the UserId and an object with a single, differently-named attribute with the count as a value.

Your reduce function would then combine the results into one (untested - I am not sure if you can just increment a non-existing property and I can't test it right now):

```
var reduceFunction = function(UserId, values_array) {
                   var ret = {};

                   for (var i = 0; i < values_array.length; i++) {
                       var values = values_array[i];
                       for (key in values) {
                           ret[key] += values[key]; // Can you increment a non-existing attribute? Not sure, try it, please.
                       }
                   }                       

                   return ret;
               };
```

You then call this like this:

```
 db.yourCollection.mapReduce(
                 mapFunction,
                 reduceFunction,
                 out: { inline: 1 }
               )
```

The line `out: { inline: 1 }` outputs the results into the console. Usually you use MapReduce to create a new collection with the results. See [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/#db.collection.mapReduce) for more information.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I have "another" Map Reduce variant. But I need this query without Map reduce. For example: by aggregate or $group or $project.... Do you know something related?

Comment: Why do you need to do it without MapReduce?

Comment: That is not condition "I can not use Map reduce". I'm begginer in Mongo and I looking for best way how resolve this problem. The simple way is use MapReduce, 
another way: I can use new collection, import data into this by filter EventId a return that (Like SQL UNION), but I think there is better way how to do it. Perhaps this way is wrong?

Comment: @Philipp, the line you were not sure about should actually look like this `isNaN(ret[k]) ? ret[k] = values[k] : ret[k] += values[k];`